# Something similar to JFrame.pack() for JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a JPanel that I want to set the width of, but let the height be determined by its content. The containing JPanel should keep its size. If I put multiple lines of text in the "content" it should of course automatically span more height. Should the needed height ever exceed the available height of the container, a scrollbar would be ideal (but that's less important).

[image]

This is probably really simple, but I just can't figure it out...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JPanelContentSizedDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(JPanelContentSizedDemo::new);
    }

    JPanelContentSizedDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        // the containing panel
        JPanel panelContainer = new JPanel();
        panelContainer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panelContainer.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 200);
        panelContainer.setBackground(Color.RED);
        frame.add(panelContainer);
        
        // what to do...
        //panelContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelContainer, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panelContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // the panel that I want to size to its content
        JPanel dialog = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        dialog.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        dialog.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        dialog.add(new JLabel("This is some content!"));
        panelContainer.add(dialog);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.setLayout(null);` This is possible to achieve with layouts. No layouts? Good luck. **More copy/pasty..** Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Your points are all valid! I set the layout for it to null on purpose, to demonstrate that I do not want the window to be made smaller, as if using pack(). Anyway, I think I found a solution using GridBagLayout, which I will post.

Comment: *"found a solution using `GridBagLayout`"* Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
    // what to do...
    panelContainer.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;

    ...

    panelContainer.add(dialog, c);
```

[image]

Comment: Ironically, a single component added to a grid bag layout with no constraints will be centered by default. No harm though in configuring a suitable constraints and adding the component using that constraint. Defaults cannot be completely relied on. E.G. the `JFrame` changed from (default) `FlowLayout` to `BorderLayout` in the distant past.

Comment: @AndrewThompson And I don't just want to know how this particular case works. I also wanted to find out how to vertically stretch and horizontally scale with content size (and different alignments), which GridBagLayout can do too. Basically WPF's StackPanel with "HorizontalAlignment NOT Stretch".